# tf.gradient acting like tfp.math.diag_jacobian

Tags: python, tensorflow, diagonal, gradient

I try to calculate noise for input data using the gradient of the loss function from the input-data:

my_grad = tf.gradients(loss, input)

loss is an array of size (n x 1) where n is the number of datasets, m is the size of the dataset, input is an array of (n x m) where m is the size of a single dataset.

I need my_grad to be of size (n x m) - so for each dataset the gradient is calulated. But by definition the gradients where i!=j are zero - but tf.gradients allocates huge amount of memory and runs for prettymuch ever...

A version, which calulates the gradients only where i=j would be great - any Idea how to get there?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose I have found a solution:

my_grad = tf.gradients(tf.reduce_sum(loss), input)

ensures, that the cross dependencies i!=j are ignored - that works really nicely and fast..

Comment: That is surprising, `tf.gradients(loss, input)` and `tf.gradients(tf.reduce_sum(loss), input)` should produce the same result and take similar computational effort.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. The reason why it works for me is:
loss =[f(input[i]) for i in range(0, input.shape[0]]
Therefore there is simply no derivative between loss[i] and input[j] when i!=j

Answer (score 0):

This is one possible approach:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [20, 50])
# Break X into its parts
x_parts = tf.unstack(x)
# Recompose
x = tf.stack(x_parts)
# Compute Y however
y = tf.reduce_sum(x, axis=1)
# Break Y into parts
y_parts = tf.unstack(y)
# Compute gradient part-wise
g_parts = [tf.gradients(y_part, x_part)[0] for x_part, y_part in zip(x_parts, y_parts)]
# Recompose gradient
g = tf.stack(g_parts)
print(g)
# Tensor("stack_1:0", shape=(20, 50), dtype=float32)
```

However this has at least two issues:

- It requires you to use a fixed size for `n` (not for `m` though).
- It will create `O(n)` nodes in the graph, which may be a problem if you intended to use a very big `n`.

In theory, a TensorFlow while loop could be used, but something in the tensor arrays or the loops does not propagate the gradients as necessary.

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, None])
n = tf.shape(x)[0]
element_shape = x.shape[1:]
x_parts = tf.TensorArray(x.dtype, size=n, dynamic_size=False,
                         element_shape=element_shape, clear_after_read=False)
_, x_parts, _ = tf.while_loop(lambda i, x_parts, x: i < n,
                              lambda i, x_parts, x: (i + 1, x_parts.write(i, x[i]), x),
                              [tf.constant(0, n.dtype), x_parts, x])
x = x_parts.stack()
y = tf.reduce_sum(x, axis=1)
g_parts = tf.TensorArray(y.dtype, size=n, dynamic_size=False,
                         element_shape=element_shape, clear_after_read=True)
_, g_parts, _ = tf.while_loop(lambda i, g_parts, x_parts, y: i < n,
                              lambda i, g_parts, x_parts, y:
                                (i + 1, g_parts.write(i, tf.gradients(y[i], x_parts.read(i))[0]), x_parts, y),
                              [tf.constant(0, n.dtype), g_parts, x_parts, y])
# Fails due to None gradients
g = g_parts.stack()
print(g)
```